# CMake How to check target for build

Tags: c++, build, cmake, build-system

I have tried to find solution: How to check target for build ?

Consider the following CMake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
project(cppTests)

# How to check at this point the target of build
if(TARGET "cppTests")
    message(STATUS "Target is cppTests")
else()
    message(STATUS "Target is not cppTests")
endif()


message(STATUS "Target is ${TARGET}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(cppTests ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Then I call the following:

```
/home/username/Software/clion-2017.1.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/username/Projects/cppTests/cmake-build-debug --target cppTests -- -j 8
```

How can I check target **cppTests** in **CMake** script after **--target** options ?
I am looking for something like **MAKECMDGOALS** in **Makefiles**.
I have found any useful solution ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT fidl_files_generated
        DEPENDS "./interfaces/*.fidl"
        COMMAND touch fidl_files_generated
        COMMAND /home/redra/Projects/Automotive/cgen/commonapi-generator/commonapi-generator-linux-x86_64 -sk ../interfaces/ *.fidl
        COMMAND /home/redra/Projects/Automotive/cgen/commonapi_dbus_generator/commonapi-dbus-generator-linux-x86_64 ../interfaces/ *.fidl
)

add_custom_target(fidl_gen
                  DEPENDS fidl_files_generated)

set(GENERATED_FILES "../cmake-build-debug/src-gen/v1/commonapi/HelloWorldDBusProxy.cpp"
                    "../cmake-build-debug/src-gen/v1/commonapi/HelloWorldDBusDeployment.cpp"
                    "../cmake-build-debug/src-gen/v1/commonapi/HelloWorldDBusStubAdapter.cpp"
                    "../cmake-build-debug/src-gen/v1/commonapi/HelloWorldStubDefault.cpp"
                    "../cmake-build-debug/src-gen/v1/commonapi/HelloWorldDBusDeployment.cpp")
set_source_files_properties(${GENERATED_FILES} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)

add_executable(
        CommonAPI_Server
        ${SOURCE_FILES}
        ${GENERATED_FILES})
add_dependencies(CommonAPI_Server fidl_gen)
```

Thanks all for support !!

Special thanks to [Angew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782465/angew) for support and help !!!!

Comment: This is all great but does not work when you do not know what GENERATED_FILES you will get :-( GLOB_RECURSE will fail here as it is operable at configuration time.
The real issue is that add_custom_command does not provide tools to get result from the command. Look at execute_process - you get return value, errors etc.
So you can't create a custom command that would "return" list of GENERATED files found in some dir :-( Nevermind just thinking loud.

Answer (score 5):

The developer chooses which target(s) to build *after* CMake has generated the project files. When CMake is being run, CMake cannot know what target the developer will build. Therefore, what you are asking for doesn't really make sense for a CMake project. In a Makefile, there is no separate configure step, it is part of the build, which is how it can provide a feature like MAKECMDGOALS. It might also be worth reconsidering if you really want this functionality of Makefiles anyway, as it [isn't meant for typical use](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) (emphasis mine):

> Make will set the special variable MAKECMDGOALS to the list of goals you specified on the command line. If no goals were given on the command line, this variable is empty. **Note that this variable should be used only in special circumstances.**

In your example, you are also misusing `if(TARGET...)`. That construct is used to test whether a particular CMake target has been *defined* by the project (which in your example it doesn't until after the `if()` command, so it would always evaluate to false). See the docs [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) for details.

Comment: I could replace MAKECMDGOALS  with add_custom_command(TARGET cppTests PRE_BUILD), but acctiaully it does not work, not in real life not according documentation of CMake. I want generate some files before build specific target. If add_custom_command(TARGET cppTests PRE_BUILD) works it would solved my issue

Answer (score 5):

What you're asking makes no sense in the CMake world. The timeline of a CMake project consists of 3 distinct steps:

```
configure time  >  generate time  >  build time
\---------------v--------------/     \---v----/
        CMake is running           make is running
```

In the **configure** step, CMake reads and parses the `CMakeLists.txt` files and stores the processed data in memory. This happens when you press the `Configure` button in CMake GUI.

In the **generate** step, CMake acts on the data in memory to generate buildsystem files (Makefiles, Visual Studio solutions & projects, etc.). This happens when you press the `Generate` button in CMake GUI.

Running `cmake` from the command line does a configure immediately followed by a generate.

Then CMake is done with the buildsystem and terminates its run. You now have a working buildsystem which can be processed by the build tool (such as `make` or `msbuild`). Even if you run this build tool using `cmake --build`, this new invocation of `cmake` does not read your `CMakeLists.txt` files at all. It just accesses the bare minimum from the generated `CMakeCache.txt` to figure out which build tool to run, and runs that.

You didn't specify what you're trying to achieve with the information, but perhaps you could work with things like [`add_custom_command(TARGET cppTests PRE_LINK)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events)?

Comment: You are not precisely right ... Actually after cmake generated files for build you can run build using cmake running command like: /home/redra/Software/clion-2017.1.1/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/redra/Projects/cppTests/cmake-build-debug --target cppTests -- -j 8

Comment: add_custom_command(TARGET cppTests PRE_LINK) - I need  add_custom_command(TARGET cppTests PRE_BUILD) to replace if else, but by some reason it does not work for Linux tools like Make. It is mentioned in documentation either

Comment: @DenisKotov I **do** mention `cmake --build`, but that's an entirely different run of CMake than the configure or generation step. "Even if you run this build tool using `cmake --build` ..." is right there in the answer. `PRE_BUILD` cannot work with Make because there's no place in the Makefile where you could reasonably put it. If you make a new question about what you actually need this for, perhaps there's an alternative way of achieving it.

Comment: My task is to generate file before build main target. CommonAPI maybe you know I need generate some files before building the target. I have implemented it with add_custom_command and add_custom_target, but I try to find alternatives

Comment: I am not quite understand why there no place for PRE_BUILD, we can create .PHONY target and this target run shell command and make a base target depends on it

Comment: @DenisKotov You could easily add the generated file to the sources of the target; that way, it will be driven by that target instead of by a custom target. Would that do what you need?

Comment: @DenisKotov Regarding `PRE_BUILD`: does make let you specify that a particular dependency must be satisfied before other dependencies are even analysed?

Comment: I can just add the generated file to the sources of the target, but this does not guaranty that it is up-to-date. If fidl-file changed I need to regenerate again this cpp file that is why I need do this before build

Comment: @DenisKotov If you do it correctly, it *does* guarantee correct re-generation. If you specify the dependencies in the `add_custom_command()` which creates the file, CMake will honour them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question properly, but, according to what I understand, you are looking for the variables `CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME` and `PROJECT_NAME`.

```
if (${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} STREQUAL "cppTests")
    message("CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME is \"cppTests\"")
else ()
    message("CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME is NOT \"cppTests\"")
endif ()
```

See a list of common variables [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables). I often keep this link open when I do CMake ; I think you will find it useful too.

Comment: No, I am looking not for ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} because at the same project can be various target with different names, for example: add_executable(cppExe ${SOURCE_FILES});add_library(cppLib ${SOURCE_FILES})

Comment: I am looking for something like MAKECMDGOALS in Makefiles